# React Native Redux AsyncStorage Returns Null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, asyncstorage

I implemented async reducer and i am trying to return asyncstorage value but when i call dispatcher it prints value in console but don't update initial state.

userReducer.js :

```
import {AsyncStorage} from "react-native";

const initialState = {
    fullname: null
}
const userReducer = async (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_USERNAME':
            const uname= await AsyncStorage.getItem('@uinfo:name', '')
            console.log('uname: '+uname)
            return { fullname: uname}
    }
    return state
}

export default userReducer;
```

In above console prints users name but dont't set the state.

I tried to Set dispatch in componentDidMount:

```
async componentDidMount() {

        const uname= await this.props.getNAME()
        console.log('uname: '+ this.props.fullname)
    }
```

**console.log('uname: '+ this.props.fullname) return undefined**

My mapDispatchToProps:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getNAME: () => dispatch({ type: 'GET_UNAME' })
    }
}
```

Do i missing something, Why the state is not setting

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Save a login token to a users device?

Comment: I already did that.. I want to fetch token via reducer? Issue is that it is stored in AsyncStorage. I can get AsycStorage directly using componentdidmount but i implemented redux. Other thinks are working fine with redux

Comment: I guess I am unclear as to why you need to fetch the token via your reducer. Your reducer should just be handling the case in which login is successful and login is a failure. Your action creator is where you would want to run something like this: `let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("fb_token");` and maybe also a lifecycle method in one of your components.

Comment: I want to store token once in reduce so that i don't have to refetch it again via AysncStorage on other screens

Answer (score 0):

**fullname** is an element from state as you assign initialState to state, so you can access fullname like this.

```
import {AsyncStorage} from "react-native";

const initialState = {
    fullname: null
}
const userReducer = async (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_USERNAME':
            const uname= await AsyncStorage.getItem('@uinfo:name', '')
            console.log('uname: '+uname)
            state.fullname = uname;
            return { ...state }
    }
    return state
}

export default userReducer;
```

Comment: just console log state in ```render(){  console.log('state', this.props )}``` and see what value it is printing. Also use **redux dev tools or redux logger** to view states in store. Check you have connecting your component correctly to store.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage.getItem()` returns promise, so the statement `return { fullname: uname}` runs before the `await` statement and once return statement gets executed the function is exited. You can try this instead

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('@uinfo:name', '').then(res=>{
  if(res)
  return { 
...state,
fullname: uname }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using it the wrong way,

actions does not return anything.

You need to map state to props using `mapStateToProps` config in connect.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({
  userReducer
}) =>{
const {fullname} = userReducer;
return fullname;
}
```

give this to connect,

```
 export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(YouClass);
```

you can access your data using, `this.props.fullname`.

`cmponentDidUpdate` and `componentWillReceiveProps` will be fired when reducer will return data.

**Note:** you have returned data from reducer like this

```
return { fullname: uname} // never do this, because you will lost all other data/variables other than fullname.
```

instead do this,

```
return { ...state,fullname: uname} //this will not do anything to other variables
```

Comment: any other ideas?